# Using LINQ to parse XML into Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

I have a configuration file such as:

```
<ConfigurationFile>
    <Config name="some.configuration.setting" value="some.configuration.value"/>
    <Config name="some.configuration.setting2" value="some.configuration.value2"/>
    ...
</ConfigurationFile>
```

I am trying to read this to XML and convert it to a Dictionary.  I tried coding something liek this but it is obviously wrong as it does not compile.

```
Dictionary<string, string> configDictionary = (from configDatum in xmlDocument.Descendants("Config")
                                               select new
                                               {
                                                   Name = configDatum.Attribute("name").Value,
                                                   Value = configDatum.Attribute("value").Value,
                                               }).ToDictionary<string, string>(Something shoudl go here...?);
```

If someone could tell me how to get this working it would be really helpful.  I could always, of course, read it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To give a more detailed answer - you can use `ToDictionary` exactly as you wrote in your question. In the missing part, you need to specify "key selector" and "value selector" these are two functions that tell the `ToDictionary` method which part of the object that you're converting is a key and which is a value. You already extracted these two into an anonymous type, so you can write:

```
var configDictionary = 
 (from configDatum in xmlDocument.Descendants("Config")
  select new {
    Name = configDatum.Attribute("name").Value,
    Value = configDatum.Attribute("value").Value,
  }).ToDictionary(o => o.Name, o => o.Value);
```

Note that I removed the generic type parameter specification. The C# compiler figures that automatically (and we're using an [overload with three generic arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx)). However, you can avoid using anonymous type - in the version above, you just create it to temporary store the value. The simplest version would be just:

```
var configDictionary = 
  xmlDocument.Descendants("Config").ToDictionary(
    datum => datum.Attribute("name").Value,
    datum => datum.Attribute("value").Value );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `ToDictionary` needs a key and value selector. Starting with that you have, it can be

```
var dictionary = yourQuery.ToDictionary(item => item.Name, item => item.Value);
```

Comment: Sorry this isn't very clear to me.  Where would this code go?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't necessary to have the query as you're just doing a projection.  Move the projection into the call to `ToDictionary()`:

```
var configDictionary = xmlDocument.Descendants("Config")
                                  .ToDictionary(e => e.Attribute("name").Value,
                                                e => e.Attribute("value").Value);
```