# Linq To Xml - Create Dictionary From Repetitive XML

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary, linq-to-xml

I have an XML string like this:

```
<root>
  <name>Key</name>
  <value>Value</value>
  <name>Key</name>
  <value>Value</value>
  <name>Key</name>
  <value>Value</value>
</root>
```

How can I produce a C# dictionary that corresponds to this - i.e for each pair of name and value create a dictionary item. (with use of Linq To XML).

Comment: see here [http://stackoverflow.com/a/4801620/474535](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4801620/474535)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this ...

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.parse(... parse you XML here ...);
var nameElements = doc.Descendants("name");
var dictionary = nameElements.ToDictionary(el => el.Value,
                                           el => el.ElementsAfterSelf().First().Value);
```

This first finds all the `name` elements, then projects this array to a dictionary. The key selector uses `el.Value`, which is the value of the `name` element. The value selector takes the next sibling of the element, which will be your `value` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ToDictionary()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx):

```
var dict = XElement.Parse(yourMarkup).Elements("name").ToDictionary(
    name => name.Value,
    name => name.ElementsAfterSelf("value").First().Value);
```